# I need to let the user input any numbers and characters and only the '-' or the '\' in a field. How do I do that with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

A user can enter a serial number with any numbers or characters and only the following special characters: '-'  '\'. 
This is what I have in my code:

```
if(/[-\\a-zA-Z0-9] /i.test(serialNumber)) {
             $('#serialErrorMsg').html('<div>Invalid format.<br>Hover over Serial Number <br>column name to see valid formats</div>');
```

When I put this into a regex editor and use the following serial; p23edf-A  as a test case my alert message comes back as invalid format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's too late (in the evening and I'm tired), but don't you mean to NOT your if expression?

```
if(! /[-\\a-zA-Z0-9]+/i.test(serialNumber)) {
```

and to test an entire string change it to

```
^[-\\a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: Further testing has revealed that this is still allowing special characters in. if(! /[-\\a-zA-Z0-9]+/i.test(serialNumber)) {
    $('#serialErrorMsg').html('<div>Invalid format.<br>Hover over Serial Number <br>column name to see valid formats</div>');

Comment: @mac3201 I have updated to test the entire string, not just any part of it